# cakephp redirect upon group of the user

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I am using acl and I want to redirect the users based on which group they are from

in my appcaontroller I have this

```
public function beforeFilter() {
                                //Configure AuthComponent
                                //$this->Auth->allow('display');
                                $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
                                $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
                                $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'add');
    }
```

what should I do so if the user is from group_id 1, he/she should be redirected to a place different than group_id = 4 etc

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so for example you are redirecting every user to an action say `dashboard`. Instead of redirecting the user to add action of `posts` controller redirect to `dashboard` of `users` controller. I am assuming you have another table for groups and you are keeping it's foreign key in users table.

```
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard');
```

The above will redirect user upon login to `dashboard` action in `users` controller. Now to take every user to a specific group, get the group name of user and redirect to specific page.

```
  function dashboard() {
      //get user's group (role)
    $group_name = $this->User->Group->field('name', array('id' => $this->Auth->User('group_id')));
    //group selection logic here
    $action = 'dashboard_' . $group_name;
    $this->redirect('controller' => 'users' => 'action' => $action);
  }
```

So the above code will take every user to specific action e.g. if group name is 'managers' user will be redirected to 'managers_dashboard'.